# Tooltip help in HighCharts Column chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am working highcharts trying to create a column chart that has a customized tooltip.I would like this tool to show the y value of the column, and a couple of other pieces of data for the position. Something like :
22,000 net
22,001 CR 
22,002 Dr
I have the series for the points set up as follows:

```
 series: [
      {
        name: 'Amount',
        data: [22000, 21000, 19000,4000,27000,1000],
        Credit:[22001, 21001, 19001,4001,27001,1001],
        Debit:  [22002, 21002, 19002,4002,27002,1002]
      }
```

and I am using a tooltip formatter function as follows:

```
  tooltip: {formatter: function(){
        return 'the value here is ' + this.y + this.point.Credit
```

But I am getting undefined for the credit value. 
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. thanks

I have a jsfiddle of this at :

http://jsfiddle.net/bryands1/5uowfx7v/9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access this kind of series data use path like:

```
this.series.options.Credit[this.point.index]
```

Example with your data: http://jsfiddle.net/5uowfx7v/32/

Answer (score 3):

You can access it in tooltip formatter function:

```
this.series.options.Credit
```

So your code would be

```
 tooltip: {
      formatter: function(){
         return 'the value here is ' + this.y + ' ' + this.series.options.Credit[0]
      }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I put this code into jsfiddle I then do not get any tooltip at all. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Do you receive any errors in the console? Have you any live demo of it?